# YetiForce CRM 500 http error

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток.
Пытаюсь поставить CRM вылазит 500 ошибка. Ubuntu 14.04 
Добавил в код просмотр ошибок, вот что вышло.

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant ROOT_DIRECTORY - assumed
'ROOT_DIRECTORY' in /var/www/html/crm/include/ConfigUtils.php on line
165

Warning: session_start():
open(cache/session//sess_50e082ac594a0b9342be6, O_RDWR) failed:
Permission denied (13) in
/var/www/html/crm/libraries/HTTP_Session/Session.php on line 160

Notice: Undefined variable: defaultLayout in
/var/www/html/crm/include/ConfigUtils.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined variable: defaultLayout in
/var/www/html/crm/include/ConfigUtils.php on line 34

Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in
/var/www/html/crm/include/runtime/Viewer.php on line 65

Fatal error: Uncaught -- Smarty: unable to write file
/var/www/html/crm/cache/templates_c/wrt594a2de49ae428_93619983 <--
thrown in
/var/www/html/crm/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_runtime_writefile.php
on line 49

Warning: Unknown: open(cache/session//sess_50e082ac594a0b9342be6,
O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify
that the current setting of session.save_path is correct
(cache/session/) in Unknown on line 0
```

Кто нибудь сталкивался?
[image: Теперь так]

Всё разобрался. Обновил до 16.04 и phph до 7. Нормально заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш веб-сервер, скорее всего Apache, не имеет прав на запись в каталог, в который вы пытаетесь установить эту CRM.

Один из вариантов исправить этот недочёт:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/crm/
```

Лучше было бы устанавливать такие программы под отдельным пользователем.

Также стоило бы устанавливать более свежую версию этой CRM. Одна из ошибок, которую вы видите, [скорее всего уже исправлена](https://github.com/YetiForceCompany/YetiForceCRM/blob/developer/include/ConfigUtils.php#L186).